# Typecast between anonymous structs with field tags

Tags: go

I had an Open API generated schema, and I would like to create the response struct in my handler function. But when I want to create the anonymous struct, I need to write again the field tags, too. Is there any solution for not needing to repeat that? Here is the minimal example

```golang
package main

// Response is generated by a tool in a separated file
type Response struct {
    Result *struct {
        Id int `json:"id"`
    } `json:"result,omitempty"`
}

func main() {
    var response Response

    response.Result = &struct {
        Id int `json:"id"`
    }{5}

    // This results in an error
    // cannot use &struct { Id int } literal (type *struct { Id int }) as type *struct { Id int "json:\"id\"" } in assignment
    response.Result = &struct {Id int}{5}
}
```

This anonymous struct is a result of [oapi-codegen](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen), when I use a complex type in the `components` part of the api definition as a response type. I think if I use a `CreateBookResponseResult` type, the code generator won't generate an anonymous struct, but I would postpone this option until I can.

```yaml
components:
  CreateBookResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      result:
        type: object
        properties:
          id:
            type: integer
```

Comment: The codegen is just producing terrible code. You need it to either not be a pointer, or be a named type.

Comment: Go doesn't allow type casting at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a named type.

```
type Response struct {
    Result *ResponseResult `json:"result,omitempty"`
}

type ResponseResult struct {
        Id int `json:"id"`
} 


var response Response
response.Result = &ResponseResult{Id: 5}
```

Comment: This is what I would like to do as the last resort. In this case I need to fragment the response definition in the yml. Like

```yml
components:
  CreateBookResponse:
    type: object
    properties:
      result:
        type: CreateResponseBookResult

  CreateResponseBookResult:
    type: object
    properties
      id:
        type: integer
```

So in the api definition I need to know that later how I would like to construct the response object.

Comment: @RichardJonas Why is using named types a last resort? One purpose of named types is to eliminate the need to write out a complicated anonymous type over and over.

Comment: Types are generated from `api.yml` - it is a swagger-like open api definition.

Comment: @RichardJonas unnamed structs are a huge burden as soon as you need to initialize them by hand, especially pointers to such types. I'd recommend you avoid them as much as you can.